# Xms, Xmx, XX:MaxPermSize, XX:PermSize - Qual a diferença?

Tags: memória, glassfish, configuração, servidor-de-aplicação

Preciso melhorar a performance e disponibilidade do meu servidor de aplicações Glassfish que de quando em quando faz com que a aplicação lance erro de OutOfMemory. Pesquisando na internet, verifiquei que eu devo alterar os seguintes parâmetros:

```
Xms
Xmx
XX:MaxPermSize
XX:PermSize
```

O que eu não consegui encontrar de forma clara foi qual a diferença entre esses parâmetros, qual o objetivo de cada um, pra que eu possa decidir acertadamente quais valores setar em cada um deles.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Memória dinâmica

O parâmetro **`Xmx`** define a quantidade má**x**ima de memória dinâmica que a Máquina Virtual java vai alocar para armazenar instâncias de objetos, valores de variáveis, entre outros.

É importante definir um valor razoavelmente maior do que a aplicação necessita em média para evitar não só erros de `OutOfMemory` como também escassez de memória, senão o *Garbage Collector* irá executar muito frequentemente e causar pausas indesejadas no programa.

O **`Xms`** define a quantidade inicial de memória dinâmica alocada no início da JVM.

É importante verificar quanto sua aplicação usa em média e definir um valor próximo disso. Dessa forma, sua aplicação não precisará de pausas para alocar memória, resultando em um desempenho maior de inicialização até o ponto em que a aplicação está executando num patamar estável.

## Memória permanente

O Java também possui outra parte da memória chamada de "estática" ou "permanente", utilizada para carregar suas classes (arquivos `.class`), internalizar Strings (*pool*), entre outras coisas.

Como regra geral, a memória permanente não pode ser desalocada. Isso implica que, se sua aplicação tem muitos Jars e classes, em algum momento ocorrerá um erro de *PermGen space*.

O erro ocorre porque não é possível ao Java carregar novas classes quando não há espaço na memória permanente, pois não dá para descartar classes já carregadas para dar lugar a novas.

Aqui entram os outros dois parâmetros. O **`XX:MaxPermSize`** define a quantidade máxima de memória permanente que a Máquina Virtual pode utilizar. O **`XX:PermSize`** define o tamanho inicial dela.

## Exemplo

A imagem a seguir ilustra os conceitos acima:

[image: JVM Memory]

Note que na parte dinâmica memória (à esquerda) há ainda uma diferença entre "nova" e "velha" geração, que são usadas, respectivamente, para armazenar objetos recém-criados que são candidatos e serem desalocados rapidamente de objetos criados há mais tempo, com menos chance de desalocação.

Comment: Beleza, bastante explicativo. Só fiquei com uma outra dúvida: no mesmo servidor eu tenho o JBoss e o Glassfish instalados. Cada servidor de aplicação com uma aplicação Java rodando. No JBoss já está configurada essa parte de memória. Se eu configurar no Glassfish, vai interferir na configuração que foi feita no JBoss? Pode ter algum conflito de configurações ou a JVM se comporta de forma distinta pra cada servidor de aplicação?

Comment: @Electus Cada instância da JVM é independente e não interfere nas demais, a não ser na disputa por recursos como CPU e disco. Também cuidado para que a soma da memória configurada nas duas não ultrapasse a quantidade de memória RAM, caso contrário você pode acabar com paginação de memória em disco.

Comment: Acho que vale citar que a memória permanente foi removida no Java 8