# Java ScheduleExpression

Tags: java, thread, jboss, scheduler

Estou desenvolvendo um Software de supervisionamento de Nobreaks, estou utilizando a `ScheduleExpression` que executa a cada 5 segundos, segue-se código:

```
@PostConstruct
public void agendarMonitoramento(){


    System.out.println("=================================================================================================");
    System.out.println("Iniciando monitoramento");
    System.out.println("=================================================================================================");

    upsIndividual   = nobreaksEjb.getCadNobreaskMonitoramentoIndividual();


    ScheduleExpression scheduleExpression = new ScheduleExpression().second("*/5").minute("*").hour("*");

    final TimerConfig nobreaksIndividuais = new TimerConfig(NOBREAK_SEM_BANCO_UPS, false);
    timerService.createCalendarTimer(scheduleExpression, nobreaksIndividuais);
    System.out.println("Iniciado...");

}

@Timeout
public void timeout(Timer timer) {

    for (CadNobreak cadNobreak : upsIndividual) {
        tHNobreak.monitorarNobreak(cadNobreak);
    }

}
```

Porém tenho um problema, identifiquei através do VisualVm que estas Threads estão sempre ativas, e estão causando um `OutOfMemory`, abaixo pode ser visto o número de Threads ativas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Gostaria de saber porque estas Threads não são encerradas após sua execução, e o que eu posso fazer para resolver este problema.

Exception ocorrida:

```
03:06:42,426 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 7) JBAS014120: Error invoking timeout for timer: [id=2b26961a-daf9-4a2a-aa91-144d43be2190 timedObjectId=prati.supervisorio.nobreaks.prati.supervisorio.nobreaks.ejb.MonitoramentoEjb auto-timer?:false persistent?:false timerService=org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl@2fa0052a initialExpiration=Fri Nov 14 00:00:00 BRST 2014 intervalDuration(in milli sec)=0 nextExpiration=Sat Nov 15 02:20:25 BRST 2014 timerState=ACTIVE: javax.ejb.EJBException: JBAS014580: Unexpected Error
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:186) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.TimerCMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(TimerCMTTxInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:274) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:339) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:238) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimedObjectInvokerImpl.callTimeout(TimedObjectInvokerImpl.java:101) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimedObjectInvokerImpl.callTimeout(TimedObjectInvokerImpl.java:111) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.task.CalendarTimerTask.callTimeout(CalendarTimerTask.java:62) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.task.TimerTask.run(TimerTask.java:132) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Comment: Qual a versão do JBoss?

Comment: JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA (AS 7.3.0.Final-redhat-14)

Comment: Editado, grotesco o número de Threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema resolvido, o número elevado de Threads não estava associado ao `TimerService` do Java, e sim a um objeto do protocolo SNMP que mantém `Threads` ativas, como pode ser visto abaixo

```
private void start() throws IOException {
    TransportMapping<?> transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
    snmp = new Snmp(transport);
    // Do not forget this line!
    transport.listen();

}
```

E o acúmulo de Threads ocorria que a cada ciclo o objeto era instanciando:

```
clientSnmp  = new SnmpClient(String.format("udp:%s/161", ipNobreak), timedout);
```

Mantendo todas as Threads em memória consumindo os rescursos do servidor, agora mantenho uma única instância deste objeto ativo, para evitar redundâncias.

Answer (score 2):

Os servidores de aplicação criam um *pool* de threads para a execução para evitar a criação e destruição das mesmas a cada execução.

## Threads

Se você depurar um servidor de aplicação qualquer, por exemplo, verá que ele cria pelo menos algumas dezenas de threads para atender às solicitações dos usuários quando elas chegarem.

O gráfico de threads está estranho porque apresenta por volta de 4 mil threads. Isso pode ser um erro do servidor de aplicação ou, mais provável, uma implementação equivocada do sistema que inicia algum serviço com parâmetro incorreto ou múltiplas vezes sem necessidade.

Verifique a qual serviço a maioria das threads pertencem para encontrar o culpado.

## Memória

Porém, isso não deve ter nada a ver com seu problema de falta de memória. Para verificar a causa disto, teríamos que analisar quais dependências você está usando e a cargo do processo realizado a cada execução das tarefas.

O gráfico de memória que você está mostrando é algo normal. A criação de objetos ao longo do tempo vai consumindo a memória e quando chega próximo do limite o coletor (Garbage Collector) executa, removendo os objetos não mais referenciados. Então não parece haver estouro da memória dinâmica.

Por outro lado, não posso dizer o mesmo da memória permanente (PermGen), onde ficam internalizadas as Strings e ficam armazenadas as classes da sua aplicação. É comum haver estouro dessa memória quando usamos muitas bibliotecas e em projetos que são grandes. Se for este o caso, talvez seja necessário aumentar a memória permanente disponível.

Enfim, quando falamos em problemas de memória, é sempre bom especificar exatamente qual o problema, pois o gerenciamento de memória em Java não é tão simples quanto se pensa.

Se quiser ler um pouco sobre o assunto, veja [esta outra resposta aqui do SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/37885/227).

Comment: Particularmente achei este Pool de Threads muito elevado, deixarei meu JBoss ativo de hoje para amanhã de manhã para ver o que consigo capturar, no fim de semana o erro que aconteceu não foi muito conclusivo, eu havia configurado um Queue com o HornetQueue, mas não estava usando o mesmo. Não sei se isso poderia ter afetado. Editei meu tópico, como pode ser visto, o erro está associado com Pool de Threads.

Comment: @EderF.Freitas Realmente o pool está bem grande. Não havia reparado na grandeza. Todas essas threads são do seu timer?

Comment: Sim, no mínimo uns 90%, porque quando eu faço deploy sem o Timer cai para umas 200 no máximo. Para reproduzir o problema é simples, só utilizar o trecho de código que postei, substituindo o conteúdo por algo qualquer.